# group the json data and sum the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of json value. I want to group the data based on all geo

`Identified`,`Proposal Submitted`,`QO under Evaluation`,`Negotiation & Contracting`,`Closed Lost`,`Closed Won` by `count` and `pipelinevalue`

I want to group the json response as

```
[{SalesStage: "Identified",count:123,pipelinevalue:8},
 {SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",count:24,pipelinevalue:6},
 {SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation",count:11,pipelinevalue:2},
 {SalesStage: "Qualified",count:8,pipelinevalue:11},
 {SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting",count:7,pipelinevalue:16},
 {SalesStage: "Closed Lost",count:37,pipelinevalue:2},
 {SalesStage: "Closed Won",count:4,pipelinevalue:4}]
```

```js
const data=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 34, pipelinevalue: 5},
     {Geo: "APAC", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 62, pipelinevalue: 2},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 27, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 1},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 14, pipelinevalue: 4},
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 1},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 9, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 6},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 4},
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 8},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 8} ,
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 37, pipelinevalue: 2},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 4}];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go . Created a result obj to store the finalResult where key is SalesStage and value is full Obj.

If result does not has any property of current SalesStage add it.
If it has the property of SalesStage add the count and pipelinevalue of current obj to the exsiting in result.

```js
const data=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 34, pipelinevalue: 5},
     {Geo: "APAC", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 62, pipelinevalue: 2},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 27, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 1},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 14, pipelinevalue: 4},
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 1},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 9, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 6},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 4},
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1},
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 8},
     {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 8} ,
     
     {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 37, pipelinevalue: 2},
     
     {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 4}];
     
var result = {};

data.forEach( obj => {
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(obj.SalesStage)){
        
        var tempObj = result[obj.SalesStage];
        tempObj.count+=obj.count;
        tempObj.pipelinevalue+=obj.pipelinevalue;
        result[obj.SalesStage]=tempObj;
   }else {
        result[obj.SalesStage] = obj;
  }

})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `forEach`

```js
const data=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 34, pipelinevalue: 5}, {Geo: "APAC", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 62, pipelinevalue: 2}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 27, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 14, pipelinevalue: 4}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 9, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 6}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 4}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 8}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 8} , {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 37, pipelinevalue: 2}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 4}];
     var counts={}
     data.forEach(o=>{
       const {SalesStage, count, pipelinevalue}=o
      if (!counts[o.SalesStage]) {counts[o.SalesStage] ={SalesStage:SalesStage,count:count,pipelinevalue:pipelinevalue}}
      else {counts[o.SalesStage]={SalesStage:SalesStage,count:count+counts[o.SalesStage].count,pipelinevalue:pipelinevalue+counts[o.SalesStage].pipelinevalue}}
     })
     console.log(Object.values(counts))
```

Comment: This is also working fine.thanks.I can accept only one answer.

Comment: You're Welcome, and happy coding

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), `Object.values` and spread operators.

```js
const data = [{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'Identified',count:34,pipelinevalue:5},{Geo:'APAC',SalesStage:'Identified',count:62,pipelinevalue:2},{Geo:'US East',SalesStage:'Identified',count:27,pipelinevalue:1},{Geo:'NSU',SalesStage:'Proposal Submitted',count:4,pipelinevalue:1},{Geo:'US East',SalesStage:'Proposal Submitted',count:14,pipelinevalue:4,},{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'Proposal Submitted',count:6,pipelinevalue:1,},{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'QO under Evaluation',count:2,pipelinevalue:1,},{Geo:'US East',SalesStage:'QO under Evaluation',count:9,pipelinevalue:1,},{Geo:'NSU',SalesStage:'Qualified',count:1,pipelinevalue:6},{Geo:'US East',SalesStage:'Qualified',count:1,pipelinevalue:4},{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'Qualified',count:6,pipelinevalue:1},{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'Negotiation & Contracting',count:3,pipelinevalue:8,},{Geo:'US East',SalesStage:'Negotiation & Contracting',count:4,pipelinevalue:8,},{Geo:'US West',SalesStage:'Closed Lost',count:37,pipelinevalue:2},{Geo:'NSU',SalesStage:'Closed Won',count:4,pipelinevalue:4},];

const finalResult = Object.values(data.reduce((result, {SalesStage, count, pipelinevalue}) => {
//There could be a chance(for the first time) that in result object the 
//corresponding SalesStage object might not be available, so result[SalesStage] 
//will be undefined. Hence using {count: 0, pipelinevalue: 0} if it is undefined.
  const obj = result[SalesStage] || {count: 0, pipelinevalue: 0};
  return {
    ...result,
    [SalesStage]: {
      ...obj,
      SalesStage,
      count: obj.count + count,
      pipelinevalue: obj.pipelinevalue + pipelinevalue
    }
  }
}, {}));

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: Recreating accumulator upon each iteration may slow down the performance, on the other hand using `Map` instead of object may boost that method [dramatically](https://jsbench.me/a5kcz1719k/1)

Comment: I have used object as initial value so that the objects can be accessed faster. I didn't think that destructuring in the loop will reduce the performance that much. Thank you very much for providing the useful info @YevgenGorbunkov

Answer (score 0):

Try to run code below. I created a json object, named "sales_stage", for the final response. Hope it will be solution to your answer.

```js
        const data=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 34, pipelinevalue: 5}, {Geo: "APAC", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 62, pipelinevalue: 2}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 27, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 14, pipelinevalue: 4}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "QO under Evaluation", count: 9, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 6}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 4}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1}, {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 8}, {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Negotiation & Contracting", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 8} , {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 37, pipelinevalue: 2}, {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 4}];
        
var sales_stage = {"Identified": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "Proposal Submitted": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "QO under Evaluation": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "Qualified": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "Negotiation & Contracting": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "Closed Lost": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}, "Closed Won": {count:0, pipelinevalue:0}}
   
for (i in data) {
    let item = data[i];  
    sales_stage[item.SalesStage].count += item.count;
    sales_stage[item.SalesStage].pipelinevalue += item.pipelinevalue;
}
 console.log (sales_stage)
```